# How to get x, y, width, height of UIView which is using auto layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout, calayer

I am trying to set mask on my `blue UIView` for which I have to set `frame` for mask but problem is `blue UIView` is using `auto layout`.

How can I get `x, y, width, height` of `UIView` which is using `auto layout` to use like this `[self.v.layer.mask setFrame:CGRectMake(?, ?, ?, ?)];`.

Is using `frame` property like `self.v.frame.size.width;` is correct while using `auto layout`? or is there any other approach of getting an `UIView x, y, width, height` which is using `auto layout`.

Please see the screen shot below.

[image]

Comment: are you not able to achieve what you are looking for using `self.v.frame.size.width` ?

Comment: @iphondroid what I read is not use frame when using auto layouts. I have no idea that I am getting correct or wrong values.

Answer (score 0):

You won't get/set the correct frame when using autolayout system. If you really want to do this. You can use below method

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
}
```

it is recommended that you should use constraints to update the size/position of your view by updating the constraints.

eg: make IBOutlet of you view's constraint and view and then update like this

```
self.myViewWidthConstraint.constant += 20;
[self.myView updateConstraints];
```

To get the width you should use

```
self.myViewWidthConstraint.constant;
```

Answer (score -1):

When people talk about not using frames with autolayout they mean 'don't *set* frames that are handled by autolayout', because autolayout will handle setting the frame correctly. Reading the frame's value is not a problem.

But be aware that the frame's value may be changed by autolayout whenever the view is laid out. So you may need to put your update code in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, e.g.:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    self.blueView.layer.mask.frame = self.blueView.bounds;
}
```

Also be aware that if your mask layer is drawn based on its frame, it will need to redraw its content whenever its frame changes.